# Get value from codebehind to another view in Silverlight MVVM

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, mvvm

In my project(Silverligth with MVVM pattern) I have 2 views (Customer and CustomerDetails pages).
In Customer page I have one `ListView` and one `Button` for open the selected projects that are already loaded in the `ListView`.

`ListView` XAML Coding:(Customer.xaml)

```
 <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Projects,Mode=TwoWay}"       
             SelectedItem="{Binding Project,Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionMode="Single">
       <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
          <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          </ItemsPanelTemplate>
       </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
       <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProjectName,Mode=OneWay}" />
         </DataTemplate>
       </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  </ListBox>



    <TextBlock Name="CustomerName" Text="{Binding Customer.CustomerName}" />
      <TextBlock Name="ProjectName"  Text="{Binding Project.ProjectName,Mode=OneWay}"/>
      <TextBlock Name="Description" Text="{Binding Project.Description}" />
      <HyperlinkButton Content="Open" Click="HyperlinkButton_Click"></HyperlinkButton>
```

Actually if I select any projectFile Name from the `ListView` then click the Hyberlink `Button` means I'm getting the value to be bound to the `TextBlock` in the Customer View perfectly.

But my requirement is: the same (bound) value to be bound, when I'm navigating to the CustomerDetails page.

Customer(Code-Behind) Page:

```
private void HyperlinkButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
    iRegionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("RootRegion", typeof(View.CustomerDetails));
    iRegionManager.RequestNavigate("RootRegion", new Uri("CustomerDetails",   
                                                         UriKind.Relative));
   }
```

CustomerViewModel.cs

```
private IEnumerable<Project> projects;
private Project project;
private Customer customer;
SampleDomainContext _context;
public IEnumerable<Project> Projects
{
    get { return projects; }
    set
    {
        projects = value;
        if (projects != null)
        {
            Project = projects.FirstOrDefault();
            OnPropertyChanged("Project");
        }
    }
}
public Customer Customer
{
    get
    {
        return customer;
    }
    set
    {
        customer = value;
    }
}

public Project Project
{
    get
    {

        return project;
    }
    set
    {
        project = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Project");
        if (project != null)
        {
            Customer = project.CustomerProjects.FirstOrDefault().Customer;
            OnPropertyChanged("Customer");
        }
    }
}
  public CustomerViewModel()
    {

       int s =Common.ActiveData.Instance.userid;
       if(s!=0)
       {
         UserName = Common.ActiveData.Instance.UserName;
         OnPropertyChanged("UserName");
         GetProjectList(Common.ActiveData.Instance.userid);

       }
    }

    public void GetProjectList(int userid)
    {
        _context = new PartsDomainContext();
       _context.Load(_context.GetProjectListQuery(ActiveData.Instance.userid), Param =>
        {
            if (!Param.HasError)
            {

                Projects = Param.Entities;
                OnPropertyChanged("Projects");

            }
        }, null);
    }
```

At my CustomerDetailsview Page I have the folling controls:

textblock
textblock
textblock

[Save Button] [Cancel Button]

I need to bind the selected `ListBox` value to the TextBlocks.

Answer (score 2):

Extract the data to be binded on more than one viewmodel into a new class like:

```
public class CustomerCommonDataViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public Project SelectedProject {get; set;} // Implement it notifying the change.
}
```

Add a notifying property to both viewmodels (Customer and CustomerDetails) to this singleton and **pass the same CustomerCommonDataViewModel instance** to both.

```
public class CustomerViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public CustomerCommonDataViewModel CommonData {get; set;} // Implement it notifying the change.
}

public class CustomerDetailsViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public CustomerCommonDataViewModel CommonData {get; set;} // Implement it notifying the change.
}
```

In xaml change the bindings to this new property:

```
{Binding CommonData.Projects}
{Binding CommoData.SelectedProject}
```

Comment: Already i selected the value from listview and i hold the value in the CustomerDataContext. Now i need to refer this datacontext to CustomerDetailsViewmodel..

Comment: Sorry @JasperManickaraj, I can't understand your question. Can you please review my answer again? Did you extracted the data do you want to share between booth ViewModels ino a new class?

Comment: Actually in my first page ie., Customer page i have get the selected value in TextBlock .. now i need to pass the seleceted value to the CustomerDetails viewmodel..

Comment: You are not thinking in a MVVM way. In MVVM, you don't depend on controls to pass values. Instead, you depend on your ViewModels. Then your views must bind to the ViewModels, leaving no interaction between views. Therefore, you can forget about your TextBox containing the value an apply the technique I described here.